# Delphi 2010 virtual keyboard, start with CapsLock on?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, virtual-keyboard, capslock

Delphi 2010 Enterprise

How can I automatically turn the CapsLock on when the virtual keyboard is displayed.

Answer (score 6):

Try this on your FormCreate:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyKeys: array of tagInput;
begin
  setLength(MyKeys, 2);
  MyKeys[0].Itype:=INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  MyKeys[0].ki.wVk:=VK_CAPITAL;
  MyKeys[0].ki.wScan:=0;
  MyKeys[0].ki.dwFlags:=4;
  MyKeys[0].ki.time:=0;
  MyKeys[0].ki.dwExtraInfo:=0;

  MyKeys[1].Itype:=INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  MyKeys[1].ki.wVk:=VK_CAPITAL;
  MyKeys[1].ki.wScan:=0;
  MyKeys[1].ki.dwFlags:=4+2;
  MyKeys[1].ki.time:=0;
  MyKeys[1].ki.dwExtraInfo:=0;
  SendInput(2, MyKeys[0], sizeof(tagInput));
end;
```

You can find more info on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That code *presses* the caps-lock key. You might want to add another keyboard event to simulate the *release* of the key.